# How does \textit work?

Tags: fonts, italic

I want to know: how does `\textit` commands work? Does it use a different font (italic shaped font)? Or is it just a pure LaTeX command that changes text shape to italic?

**My main problem:** How to make a  backward *it-shaped* text?

Comment: It uses a different font.  As to left-handed writing, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245751/left-handed-writing.  If you replace `\ECFSkeetch` with `\itshape` in my answer to that question, you will see backslanted italic.  However, the proper way to do it is to design a left-slanted italic font, rather than left-slanting a right-slanted font design.

Comment: Thanks @StevenB.Segletes. Are you sure? But I think LATEX is a powerful tool and it maybe possible.

Comment: Yes, `\itshape` calls a different font.  However, there is a function `\slshape` that slants the roman font text.  The rightward slant is built in to the command, but I think some clever code can redefine the slant value.  See this answer for how to employ `FakeSlant` when using XeLaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128562/how-to-use-fakeslant-as-slanted-but-not-italic-font-with-fontspec

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: no, wait, `\slshape` invokes a different font too.  For example, `cmsl` for the Computer Modern meta-family.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Darn.  Busted!

Comment: This question has an answer than might help explain the font situation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162622/what-is-the-difference-between-normal-text-and-roman-upright

Comment: The answer to this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/displaying-medieval-scriptures-and-neumes-in-tex, shows how slant can be introduced before a font gets into LaTeX, during the period of creation of the `ttf2tfm` process and the `afm2tfm` process.  Also, slant can be introduced via the `.map` file.

Comment: This is by no means an answer (indeed, it’s a comment :-) , but just to give a hint,you could use a virtual font that just replicates the characters of some upright font, and then include in your source file a `\pdfmapline` that instructs the PDF viewer to slant that font as you wish.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210870/slanted-text-to-the-left

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nothing I'd do, but, with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX,…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\backitshape}{lmroman10-italic}[
  Extension=.otf,
  FakeSlant=-0.4,
]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbackit}{\backitshape}

\begin{document}

Some text \textit{in italic} and \textbackit{backwards tilted italic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your title question is easy to answer: `\textit` chooses a different font.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Extreme ugly but nevertheless smart. ;-)

Comment: @Schweinebacke Somehow I find it not just ugly, but really disturbing on some deep aesthetic level. There are lots of ugly fonts out there, but this one is something else :). And of course +1 for answering the question... even at the price of unleashing *that* upon the world.

Comment: That it can be done does not mean that it should be done. I don't know which is the appropriate term, hideous or atrocious. Virtuous TeXing, however ;)